# Android - How to tap ListView item programmatically

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

How to call `ItemClickListener` programmatically? `listView.performItemClick()` does not work. Is that possible?

Comment: performItemClick is supposed to work, there is probably something wrong with the way you use it

Comment: @cool dev have a look at my new answer

Answer (score 70):

```
mList.performItemClick(
    mList.getAdapter().getView(mActivePosition, null, null),
    mActivePosition,
    mList.getAdapter().getItemId(mActivePosition));
```

Where mActivePosition is your click position!

Comment: this will actually create a new view just so performItemClick will work, yes it will work, but this will not be the same view as intended, getView in adapter is misleading, it actually creates a view, and listView is using it in order to populate the views and recycle them

Comment: This won't create a view. `mList.performItemClick(mList.getChildAt(mActivePosition),
    mActivePosition,
    mList.getAdapter().getItemId(mActivePosition));`

Comment: @Arst, Thank you very much for a perfect solution.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to click/tap/select 3rd list item then.

```
listView.performItemClick(listView.getAdapter().getView(3, null, null), 3, listView.getItemIdAtPosition(3));
```

This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 4):

Assign tag in the adapter to each `View`, and `findviewByTag()` this worked for me:

```
listView.performItemClick(listView.findViewWithTag(listView.getAdapter().getItem(selectedIndex)), selectedIndex, listView.getAdapter().getItemId(selectedIndex));
```

Also refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8699551/1702512).

Answer (score 2):

If you need it for testing purposes, then you can use Robotium ( http://code.google.com/p/robotium/ ).

You could also achieve what you want by calling the `onClick` method of the `ClickController` with the correct parameters.

Comment: But how do you use Robotium to do this?

Comment: Ask robotium to tap the text inside the list item.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

listView1.performItemClick(listView1, 3, listView1.getItemIdAtPosition(3));

from the link

http://mantascode.com/?p=486

Answer (score 0):

This will work!!

```
 listview.performItemClick(listview.getChildAt(position),
                    position,
                    listview.getChildAt(position).getId());
```

Answer (score -6):

You can set up an `onItemClick` listener for your list view via

```
listView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void   onClick(View v) {
        //here you do something
    }
});
```

Comment: The question is "How to tap ListView item programmatically?" and not about getting list item click event.