# Fire listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() without user interferance

Tags: android, android-listview

Any idea how to automatically fire `onItemClick` :

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
```

under the `setOnItemClickListener` of a ListView :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
```

without user interference.

Comment: clear your question first.

Comment: have you try `Mylistview.setItemChecked(position, true);`?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820175/android-how-to-tap-listview-item-programmatically and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788688/programmatically-select-item-listview

Comment: try this way `list.performItemClick(list.getChildAt(0),0,list.getAdapter().getItemId(0));`

Comment: I have created Activity extends FragmentActivity and under "onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)" called custom adaptor to bind the listview. and setOnItemClickListener on listview. normally working fine if user click on list item but I want to execute automatically so i hide the intermediate listview (this).

Comment: @user2717440 why do you need such a requirement. Its UI and you should leave it to the user to decide to click or not click.

Comment: don't want to show this listview to user but task should be performed on the basis of this listview.

Comment: If the requirement is to hide the listview, why don't you just set its visibility to gone?