# Fire onItemClick event without the user do something

Tags: android

So I have an `AutoCompleteTextview` which works fine, but I would like to know how to enforce a specific option.
The meaning is to use something like `setText()`, but `setText` is not good for me, because it doesn't activate the `onItemClick` event, and this is what I want to activate.

```
myAutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView,                                                   ()int position, long id) {
               // do something...
   }
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You mean you want to call `onItemClick` function programmatically?

Comment: for that you can use AsynchTask.

Comment: @Abhishek yes Abhishek. exactly !

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9820175/android-how-to-tap-listview-item-programmatically

Comment: @Abhishek thanks but the link you supplied leads to ListView example. My question is about an AutoCompleteTextView. An AutoCompleteTextView doesn't have the function "performItemClick()".

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the listener as a member variable and force call it from outside, like this:

```
void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     // setContentView and other stuff
     myAutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(mOnItemListener);
}


AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mOnItemListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView,int position, long id) {
               // do something...
   }
};
```

and when you need to force call it, use:

```
mOnItemListener.onItemClick(/*put your forced parameters here*/);
```

for example:

```
mOnItemListener.onItemClick(null, null, 10, 20);
```

Comment: I understood what you wrote except the last row. Lets say I want to force the option "abc" to get selected. What  are the arguments I need to specify? I've read that http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html  and it didn't help.

Comment: You need to pass the position of row

Comment: I passed the position by the 2 last arguments and it didn't work. Maybe the first 2 arguments are the problematic ones? null,null...